# Spring Rest Url ID Validation in DB - Eg: universities/{universityId}/campuses/{campusId}/buildings

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-validator

I wanted to know the best practice of how to validate the ID of the path of my Rest API.

For example:

When I do a GET to retrieve a Building, I need to validate first if the {universityId} and {campusId} are actually valid (Existing in the DB) before proceeding.

Right now I have implemented a custom RepositoryValidation that provides those functionalities by throwing a ResourceNotFoundException() and those methods are called in my service class for the GET,PUT,POST..etc

Is there a better way to do the validation? I have read about Interceptors or Filters but not sure if that's the best practice.

Custom Exception:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

public ResourceNotFoundException() {
    super();
}

public ResourceNotFoundException(String message) {
    super(message);
}
```

Repository Validation:

```
@Component
public class RepositoryValidation {

@Autowired
private UniversityRepository universityRepository;

@Autowired
private CampusRepository campusRepository;

@Autowired
private BuildingRepository buildingRepository;

public void checkIfUniversityExists(Long universityId){
    if (!universityRepository.exists(universityId))
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("University with id: " + universityId + " not found");
}

public void checkIfCampusExists(Long campusId){
    if (!campusRepository.exists(campusId))
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Campus with id: " + campusId + " not found");
}

public void checkIfBuildingExists(Long buildingId){
    if (!buildingRepository.exists(buildingId))
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Building with id: " + buildingId + " not found");
}

}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class BuildingService {

@Autowired
private BuildingRepository buildingRepository;

@Autowired
private RepositoryValidation repositoryValidation;

public Iterable<Building> list(Long campusId) {
    return buildingRepository.findAllByCampusId(campusId);
}

@Transactional
public Building create(Building building) {
    return buildingRepository.save(building);
}

public Building read(Long buildingId,Long campusId) {

    repositoryValidation.checkIfCampusExists(campusId);
    repositoryValidation.checkIfBuildingExists(buildingId);

    return buildingRepository.findBuildingByIdAndCampusId(buildingId,campusId);
}

@Transactional
public Building update(Long buildingId,Building update) {

    repositoryValidation.checkIfBuildingExists(buildingId);

    Building building = buildingRepository.findOne(buildingId);
    building.setBuildingName(update.getBuildingName());

    return buildingRepository.save(building);
}

@Transactional
public void delete(Long buildingId,Long campusId) {

    repositoryValidation.checkIfCampusExists(campusId);
    repositoryValidation.checkIfBuildingExists(buildingId);

    buildingRepository.deleteBuildingByIdAndCampusId(buildingId, campusId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Springs' [Validation-Beanvalidation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation).

With this, you can use `@Valid` to do simple validations on properties, for example:

```
    @NotNull
    @Size(max=64)
    private String name;
```

You can also add the `@Valid` to inputs in a REST endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping("/foo", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void processFoo(@Valid Foo foo) { /* ... */ }
```

For your needs, you could consider creating a custom `@Constraint`. 
You would first create the constraint annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy=MyConstraintValidator.class)
public @interface MyConstraint {
}
```

And then the constraint validator:

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;

public class MyConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator {

    @Autowired;
    private Foo aDependency;

    ...
}
```

Notice you can inject other Spring beans into the `ConstraintValidator` as well.
Once implemented, this could easily be re-used and looks very concise.